# Run a playbook on hosts with a specific parameter

Tags: ansible

In my host file I have:

```
[web]
192.168.1.1:8682 master="yes"
192.168.1.1:8682 master="no"
```

and in my playbook I would like to run roles only on the server with master=yes like:

```
---
- name: Switch MySQL master
  hosts: web[master=yes]
  remote_user: andy
  become: yes

  roles:
    - replication_setup_switch_server
...
```

Is it possible to do that with Ansible ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ansible, but a solution would be to create separate groups for masters and non-masters.

Comment: yes but 99% of my playbooks have to ran on this 2 servers, I just have one playbook where the role has to be specific

Comment: So? Hosts can be in multiple groups. You can keep `web`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ansible you can create ad-hoc groups based on facts using [group_by](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/group_by_module.html) module.

Add a new play before `Switch MySQL master` and create a new group in it. I called the new play `Create groups by role` in the example below. You could maybe rename the variable `master` to `role` to make the playbook more intuitive. So, the inventory and the playbook would become:

```
---
[web]
192.168.1.1:8682 role="master"
192.168.1.1:8682 role="slave"

---
- name: Create groups by role
  hosts: web
  tasks:
    - name: Group by web role
      group_by:
        key: "web_{{ role }}"

- name: Switch MySQL master
  hosts: web_master
  remote_user: andy
  become: yes

  roles:
    - replication_setup_switch_server
```